# Emacs 24's python.el + ipython cannot complete module names

Tags: completion, python, emacs24.4, ipython

I'm using Emacs 24.4.1 on OSX (installed with Homebrew), with the built in `python.el`, and Python 3 (also installed with Homebrew), along with IPython 2.3.0. I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/ipython3"
 python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-completion-setup-code
 "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
 python-shell-completion-module-string-code
 "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
 python-shell-completion-string-code
 "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

Everything works correctly when I invoke `M-x run-python`, except one thing: the `<tab>`-completion of module names doesn't work in the REPL (it says "No match" in the `*Messages*` buffer). I'm pretty sure it was working with Emacs 24.3, which I upgraded very recently, but I'm not 100% sure. Anyone has an idea what might cause this, or how I could try to debug it?

**Update:**

After having set `debug-on-message` to `"No match"` as suggested by @Constantine below, trying to do:

```
In [4]: import nump<tab>
```

yields:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: "No match"
  message("%s" "No match")
  minibuffer-message("No match")
  completion--message("No match")
  completion--do-completion(#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410)
  completion--in-region-1(#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410)
  #[1028 "\n\203!\304!\203\202\305!\305\306\"F\307\310!\210\311\"*\207" [minibuffer-completion-predicate minibuffer-completion-table completion-in-region-mode-predicate completion-in-region--data markerp copy-marker t completion-in-region-mode 1 completion--in-region-1] 8 "\n\n(fn START END COLLECTION PREDICATE)"](#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410 #[771 "\211\242\301=\206\n\211\302=?\205+r\303 \304!\203\305!\202p\262q\210\306\300!$)\207" [(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote python-shell-completion-get-completions) (quote #<process Python>) (quote "import nump") args)) boundaries metadata minibuffer-selected-window window-live-p window-buffer complete-with-action] 8 "\n\n(fn STRING PRED ACTION)"] nil)
  apply(#[1028 "\n\203!\304!\203\202\305!\305\306\"F\307\310!\210\311\"*\207" [minibuffer-completion-predicate minibuffer-completion-table completion-in-region-mode-predicate completion-in-region--data markerp copy-marker t completion-in-region-mode 1 completion--in-region-1] 8 "\n\n(fn START END COLLECTION PREDICATE)"] (#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410 #[771 "\211\242\301=\206\n\211\302=?\205+r\303 \304!\203\305!\202p\262q\210\306\300!$)\207" [(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote python-shell-completion-get-completions) (quote #<process Python>) (quote "import nump") args)) boundaries metadata minibuffer-selected-window window-live-p window-buffer complete-with-action] 8 "\n\n(fn STRING PRED ACTION)"] nil))
  #[771 ":\2030@\301=\203\300\242\302A\"\303#\207\304@\305\306\307\310\311\312\300!\313\"\314\315%A##\207\304\316\"\207" [(#0) t append nil apply apply-partially make-byte-code 642 "\300\242#\207" vconcat vector [] 7 "\n\n(fn FUNS GLOBAL &rest ARGS)" #[1028 "\n\203!\304!\203\202\305!\305\306\"F\307\310!\210\311\"*\207" [minibuffer-completion-predicate minibuffer-completion-table completion-in-region-mode-predicate completion-in-region--data markerp copy-marker t completion-in-region-mode 1 completion--in-region-1] 8 "\n\n(fn START END COLLECTION PREDICATE)"]] 12 "\n\n(fn FUNS GLOBAL ARGS)"](nil nil (#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410 #[771 "\211\242\301=\206\n\211\302=?\205+r\303 \304!\203\305!\202p\262q\210\306\300!$)\207" [(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote python-shell-completion-get-completions) (quote #<process Python>) (quote "import nump") args)) boundaries metadata minibuffer-selected-window window-live-p window-buffer complete-with-action] 8 "\n\n(fn STRING PRED ACTION)"] nil))
  completion--in-region(#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410 #[771 "\211\242\301=\206\n\211\302=?\205+r\303 \304!\203\305!\202p\262q\210\306\300!$)\207" [(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote python-shell-completion-get-completions) (quote #<process Python>) (quote "import nump") args)) boundaries metadata minibuffer-selected-window window-live-p window-buffer complete-with-action] 8 "\n\n(fn STRING PRED ACTION)"] nil)
  completion-in-region(#<marker at 406 in *Python*> 410 #[771 "\211\242\301=\206\n\211\302=?\205+r\303 \304!\203\305!\202p\262q\210\306\300!$)\207" [(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote python-shell-completion-get-completions) (quote #<process Python>) (quote "import nump") args)) boundaries metadata minibuffer-selected-window window-live-p window-buffer complete-with-action] 8 "\n\n(fn STRING PRED ACTION)"] nil)
  completion-at-point()
  python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent()
  call-interactively(python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent nil nil)
  command-execute(python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent)
```

My current Emacs-fu is not enough to allow me to understand the problem from that stacktrace alone, but perhaps someone could?

Comment: To debug this, try setting `debug-on-message` to "No match" and try completing a module name; you should be able to use the backtrace to get to the source of the error. See [Error Debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks @Constantine, I have added the stacktrace above, does it give you an hint of what might be going wrong by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to Debug?

It's tough to spot until you know what you're looking for, but in the middle of the stacktrace you see that the byte-compiled functions are calling `python-shell-completion-get-completions`.

You can step through this function with `edebug` to see what's happening, or you can appeal to divine inspiration to conclude that it ultimately sends the following to the IPython interpreter:

```
';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''import nump'''))
```

On my setup (Linux but with same Emacs, python, and IPython version numbers) this command yields an empty string.  Hence why you're seeing a "No match" message.

So ... yay?  It doesn't look like there's any more debugging to do within Emacs.  Gotta figure out how to make that IPython completion command work, then adjust your configuration appropriately.

## How to Fix?

I haven't looked at Emacs, python, and IPython in a while.  I have the same configuration in my init file (I think the comments in `python.el` used to tell you to do that) but as of 24.4 it looks like a lot of IPython support is built into the default config.

So, remove the completion-related `setq` and you should be good to go.  Works for me, at least.

(Side note: I think you can remove the prompt-related `setq` as well.)

Comment: Thanks @purple_arrows, that's exactly what I ended up doing: I only have `(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/ipython3")` left, and everything else now just works.